# How to make C# winform responsive

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I want to make responsive windows form app layout that needs to be responsive to any windows size

for example, when we want to reduce windows size all elements become small as well

I have seen that some users said that we can make all elements stick or use methods but I'm looking for an efficient one and easy as well

Comment: Within winforms the correct approach is to use the `Dock` and `Anchor` properties of the controls. If you set these properties within the designer you can immediately see the effect when you change the size of the form or parent container.

Comment: Sure, but Winforms has not not really built with this task in mind. They introduced WPF also for this.

Comment: For very simple layouts, Dock and Anchor properties are enough. For more complex layouts, you can use TableLayoutPanel and/or FlowLayoutPanel controls. You can nest them for even more complex layouts, but performance will start to suffer with too many child controls. WPF provides far more flexibility than WinForms because it was built with this sort of requirement in mind.

Comment: Winforms is only really maintained because of the sheer volume of legacy apps that are still in use somehow. You should be using either WPF, or the new and improved MAUI. in terms of .net desktop apps everything else is either dead in the water or is for legacy code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like others already mentioned what you're looking for are the control properties `Dock` and `Anchor` which define how an objects size and position should change according to it's parent container.

- With `Control.Dock` you can *dock* an object to an edge of it's parent container and it will remain there even when you resize your form. An example would be a navigation menu that's always *docked* to one side of your Form.

  [image]
- With `Control.Anchor` you can *anchor* one or more edges of an object to it's parent container. That means you can place an object anywhere, *anchor* it to one or more sides and the defined sides will "stick" to it's parent containers sides when resizing.

  [image]

What could also be of use for you is the `Screen` Class ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen)) for example if you're trying to determine the Screens Resolution and set your forms Size accordingly.